# How to encrypt text using CRC32

Tags: encryption, crc32

As far as i know CRC32 is an error-detecting code.
I did not use it before but i recieve some task to use CRC32 to encrypt some text.

Is it possible to use CRC32 to encrypt ?

Comment: No. It’s a checksum, not encryption

Comment: CRC32 is not an encryption algorithm, its output is not reversible.

Comment: Check this https://eklitzke.org/crcs-vs-hash-functions and this to calculate https://md5calc.com/hash/crc32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, a CRC is linear and easily reversible, which is precisely what you *don't* want for secure encryption.

However it is possible to *encode* data with a CRC, if there were some reason to do so. You can, for example, take four bytes of data, compute the CRC-32 of that data, and transmit the CRC-32 instead of the data. Repeat for the next four bytes. That CRC-32 can easily be inverted to get the original four bytes.

I have no idea why that might be useful, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

> i recieve some task to use CRC32 to encrypt some text.

As already commented, crc32 is checksum, not even cryptographic hash. That means it lacks important features to be used in cryptography

Lets assume (wrongly) you could use crc32 as a hash function.

In theory (long shot) you could build a stream cipher e. g. [chain-hashing a key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-it-feasible-to-build-a-stream-cipher-from-a-cryptographic-hash-function). You could encrypt data with it. Just I am pretty sure the solution would be not secure enough. (even now I am an amateur and I am quite confident I see several attack vectors on such a cipher, crc32 is simply too linear)